# ML.Net TimeSeriesPrediction model Checkpoint vs retraining the model

Tags: ml.net, ml.net-model-builder

Being pretty new to ML.Net and working with TimeSeriesPrediction models and engine, I don't quite get and find enough documentation about what exactly `TimeSeriesPredictionEngine<TSrc,TDst>.CheckPoint` method does.
What I understand is that when we have a new feed in the time series we should checkpoint the model for next prediction, but can we keep doing this forever? Do we eventually need to retrain the model after a while or using the Checkpoint methods does the same thing as retraining the model with all the history?
What are the best practices in your experience?

Comment: I don't have a proper answer but the docs seem to have some useful samples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.transforms.timeseries.timeseriespredictionengine-2.checkpoint?view=ml-dotnet

Comment: It has some good examples but it doesn't answer this question.